# How do I convert malformed HTML to PDF with iText and XMLWorker?

Tags: html, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf, xmlworker

I am trying to convert HTML(with external CSS) into PDF using Itext XMLWorkerHelper,  am facing the run-time exception whenever XMLWorkerHelper parses a malformed HTML. For example:

The html below has input tag not closed : and XMLWorkerHelper cannot parse and throws run-time exception.

if i try with proper HTML input tag enclosed,it works fine.

How can i convert malformed or complex HTML (along with css) to PDF using Itext.

below is my code:

```
var test_html = File.ReadAllText("C:/Desking _ Lender Program - Dealertrack.html");
var test_css = File.ReadAllText("C:/login.css");
using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test_html)))
                        {

                            //Parse the HTML
                            try
                            {
                                iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Upgrade to iText 7 and use the pdfHTML add-on. That upgrade of XML Worker fixes the problem you mention.

Comment: Make your HTML well-formed with JSoup before you feed it to XMLWorker. pdfHtml, mentioned by Bruno, already does that for you but in iText 5 it is still a manual step.

Comment: i upgraded to Itext 7 licensed version. Can any of to point me to correct resources i can refer to and i am using c# as programming language. Please let me know if i can get some support form Itext since am using a licensed version . Thanks alot @BrunoLowagie

Comment: i have a itextsharp licensed key and i tried to use the same key for itext7 - it didnt work,  also i just downloaded a trail version key and tried to use itext7 pdfHTML - it didnt work saying license file is corrupted. @AmedeeVanGasse need help

Comment: If you are a licensed user then you don't need to use Stack Overflow, which is community support without guarantees. You can use our support system, JIRA, with the web interface or the email address that was provided to your company when you purchased. If you don't have this information then you will have to ask the person inside your company who was responsible for purchasing an iText license.

Comment: A license key for iText 5 (iTextSharp) will not work for iText 7. A license key for iText 7 will not work for IText 5.

Comment: Thanks alot. i downloaded the Itext7 trail key and got it working. Is there a sample or way to apply external css while converting html to pdf using pdfHTML. @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - Regarding the use of iTextSharp and XMLWorker 5.XX, the .NET de facto standard HTML parser is [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), maybe in large part due to the fact that the .NET port of JSoup is not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear whether you've decided to use iText7 or iTextSharp (5.x.x), but here's a simple example of the latter using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) to clean up malformed HTML:

```
var malformedHtml = @"
<h1>Malformed HTML</h1>
<p>A paragraph <b><span>with improperly nested tags</b></span></p><hr>
<table><tr><td>Cell 1, row 1</td><td>Cell 1, row 2";
HtmlDocument h = new HtmlDocument()
{
    OptionFixNestedTags = true, OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true
};
h.LoadHtml(malformedHtml);

string css = @"
h1 { font-size:1.4em; }
hr { margin-top: 4em; margin-bottom: 2em; color: #ddd; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, td { border: 1px solid black; }
td { padding: 4px; }
span { color: red; }";

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(h.DocumentNode.WriteTo())))
        {
            using (var cssStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlStream, cssStream);
            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT, stream.ToArray());
}
```

PDF output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And if you are free to choose your particular iText flavour, please go with iText7 and pdfHTML. It supercedes XMLWorker, supports a wider range of tags and CSS3.0.