# How to convert HTML to XHTML conversion to generate closed tags in iText C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I am using class iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper to add text in HTML format into a pdf file in a ASP .NET C# project. Here's my code :

```
            Paragraph bookingTemplateDescriptionContent = new Paragraph();
            desc.Content = desc.Content.Replace("</br>", "<br/>"); //HACK : To avoid exception, replace the br tag in HTML formatted to XHTML formatted
            ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(desc.Content, null);
            foreach (var element in list) {
                foreach (Chunk chunk in element.Chunks) {
                    chunk.Font = bookingTemplateDescFont;
                }

                bookingTemplateDescriptionContent.Add(element);

            }
```

But recently I got an exception : `Invalid nested tag p found, expected closing tag br.` . After googling I found that the exception is happen because there are a nested tag that does not have a valid closing tag. In my case the tag is `<p>`. I know I can do edit the HTML string manually in the database or in the application. But I think there are a better way to solve this. After googling, I found that the problem can be solved by convert the HTML text into XHTML. My question is, is there any recommendation nuGet packages that I can use to convert the HTML text into XHTML before the HTML is written into the PDF file ? Something like `JSoup` in Java. Any recommendation is welcome. Thank you. I know there are some tools like `HTML2XML` but I want to know if there are any alternative tools or other recommendation tools beside `HTML2XML`

Comment: Please upgrade to iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on, and cleaning up the HTML will be done for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext for more info (and please read the [iText 7 HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) before asking a question.

Comment: To clarify Bruno's comment: in the answer to the duplicate question, JSoup is used, and you need to include JSoup in your project yourself and write that HTML to XHTML code yourself. With iText 7 + pdfHTML, all of that it is done for you.

Comment: I initially marked this question as a duplicate of [How to do HTML to XML conversion to generate closed tags?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-do-html-xml-conversion-generate-closed-tags) but now that I've re-read the question, I see that JSoup is already mentioned. It is unclear to me why the question is still needed if the OP knows Jsoup. There are plenty of C# ports of Jsoup. I reopened the question though, so that someone who provides an answer showing how to use a C# port of JSoup can harvest some up-votes.

Comment: However: the most valid answer is mentioned in my initial comment: upgrade to iText 7 because "iTextSharp" was replaced by "iText for .NET", and XML Worker is no longer supported (unless you have a premium support contract).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, amedee van gasse Thank you for the answers, I suppose I will try to upgrade to iText 7 and using pdfHTML add-on.

Comment: The .NET de facto standard equivalant of Java's JSoup is [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), [Sample usage with V5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875060).

Comment: @kuujinbo Thank you for the answer, adding alternative solution for my question