# ASP.NET MVC : iTextSharp XHTML Closing tags error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, itext, xhtml

I am trying to convert HTML(razor View in ASP.NET MVC) to PDF using iTextSharp. I am getting error for empty tags like `<br />`, `<hr />`. The error is `Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag br.` When I comment all such tags it works fine and generates pdf. I tried using `<br></br>` instead of `<br />` but that isn't working either. Below is controller code

```
public FileResult Export(string GridHtml)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
            }
        }
```

Getting error on `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);`
 Have researched a lot on net but somehow unable to find a solution. I am doing it for first time, so not sure if I am missing something. Please advise.

Comment: No one can help you without seeing the HTML. Also: why are you still using XML Worker? You are posting a question that is an exact duplicate of [How to convert HTML to XHTML conversion to generate closed tags in iText C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558712) Please avoid duplicate questions.

Comment: Long story short: XML Worker is no longer supported, so there's a high chance you won't get an answer (unless you have a paid support agreement). You should read the [Converting HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext) question, and study the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for pointing this. Actually I am doing this for first time and researched for tutorials. So found XML worker. The link you provided suggests using pdfHTML. Will have a look into and try.

Comment: Please provide the links that told you to use XMLWorker.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/MVC-iTextSharp-Example-Convert-HTML-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx